# Need help on sorting my file alphabetically, with a simple code

Tags: python, sorting

```
f = ("name list.txt","r")
f.sort()
for lines in f:
   print(f)
```

This brings an error message saying

> "tuple" object has no attribute f.sort()

Comment: Is this Python?  Add a language tag.

Comment: Is the first line a typo? If you are trying to open a file you need to use the open function. Second a file object is not like a list, you cannot just sort it the way you did.What you could do is put all the lines in a list and then sort the list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is python,

```
f = ("name list.txt","r")
```

is not what you want.  The parentheses here create a tuple of two strings.  I believe you intended to do:

```
f = open("name list.txt","r")
```

This won't fix your problem, because a file object does not have a `sort` method either, but it's a step in the right direction.  You might be looking for `lines = f.readlines(); lines.sort()`

Comment: thanks a lot that really helped. im a beginner in python

Answer (score 1):

### Short version

You should open the file, then use the `sorted` function to do a non-in-place sort, then store that to a variable:

```
with open("name list.txt","r") as fobj:
    res = sorted(fobj)
```

`res` will be what you want, a sorted `list` of strings.

### More detailed explanation

`sorted` automatically goes through each line in the file, extracts the text from that line, then sorts all the lines.  This is because, in Python, files are considered iterables, you can loop over them line-by-line (like `for line in fobj`), and `sorted` accepts iterables.

`with` is used because it will safely close the file when everything is over, even if there is an exception.  `fobj = open("name list.txt","r")` requires you to remember to close it afterwards, and may close if there is an exception.  `with` takes cares of that all for you.

If you don't want newlines at the end of each line, do this:

```
with open("name list.txt","r") as fobj:
    res = sorted(line.strip('\n') for line in fobj)
```

This is basically the same as above, except it goes through each  line and strips the newline character before sorting.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way I can think of to do what you want:

```
with open("name list.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in sorted(f.read().splitlines()):
       print(line)
```